# Fitting a periodic function

Tags: trigonometry

I have some data, basically I want to relate two set of angles (in degrees).
(x,y)={
(-75,15)
,(-45,45)
,(-15,75)
,(15,105)
,(45,135)
,(75,165)
,(-75,195)
,(-45,225)
,(-15,255)
,(15,285)
,(45,315)
,(75,345)}.
It seems like they are related with a sin function x=A*sin(y-pi/2). But if you solve for the amplitude (using the radians of the angles mentioned above) you get these values: 1.35,
1.11,
1.01,
1.01,
1.11,
1.35,
-1.35,
-1.11,
-1.01,
-1.01,
-1.11,
-1.35. Which look like they are varying with a cos function. I just wanted to know if there was a good way of determining a relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation is perfectly linear

$$x=y-90°$$

with a $180°$ jump at $y=180°$, then

$$x=y-270°.$$

In other words,

$$x=y\bmod 180°-90°.$$

You can approximate the function as a sawtooth wave, using the Fourier series, which is a sum of sinusoids, but this complete overkill.